Jigsaw T bar guage
I have a Von Haus 400w Jigsaw. On the bottom plate there appears to be the openings from left to right or vice versa to allow a T bar gauge or device to enable the user to vary the width of the wood material they are cutting.
There are also two pre-drilled and threaded holes which could be used to lock the T bar width. No not those screws are present.
Does anyone know if that is what the bottom plate is for and more importantly where, if anywhere, I could get the T bar to fit.
I have tried without success to contact Von Haus !

do you mean a fence like this or saw guide like this, what is the width/height of the holes?

Just be aware that a fence on a jigsaw doesn’t guarantee perfect rips. Blades can wander a lot. In my opinion, you’d do better just following a line.

@AloysiusDefenestrate, gotta strongly disagree on this. A fence or running base or sub-base along a straightedge, can both make a mahooosive difference in how straight and true a jigsaw cut can be. Not a magic bullet by any means, but if you're good and patient and use the appropriate saw blade the difference can be night and day, between just rough cutting versus producing a finished cut. [Won't compare with speed and ease and likely surface finish with a cut from a circ saw, but way better than just barely adequate.]

Hi, welcome to StackExchange. If nobody can help with specific info on this saw a photo or two of the foot would go a long way to helping us provide generic advice. Worth noting that even without the specific fixing holes etc. on a base such as this a fence system can still be devised and fitted. These are possible on any jigsaw even if it doesn't have any existing holes drilled through the foot; so if you had to fit something in the interim it could be done without altering the stock openings/holes.
